# Secure Connection Failed to old printer with https

Tags: firefox, printer, ssl, chromium

For two years the solution on [Firefox: Secure Connection Failed SSL_ERROR_BAD_MAC_ALERT](https://superuser.com/questions/1280239/firefox-secure-connection-failed-ssl-error-bad-mac-alert/1280240) worked. But no more.

Firefox gives:

> **Secure Connection Failed**
>
> An error occurred during a connection to mysite. SSL peer reports incorrect Message Authentication Code.
>
> Error code: SSL_ERROR_BAD_MAC_ALERT
>
> - The page you are trying to view cannot be shown because the authenticity of the received data could not be verified.
> - Please contact the website owners to inform them of this problem.

But does not give an option to proceed anyway.

I tried the same with Iridium:

> **This site can’t be reached**
>
> The webpage at mysite might be temporarily down or it may have moved permanently to a new web address.
>
> ERR_SSL_BAD_RECORD_MAC_ALERT

Iridium also does not give an option to "add exception".

How can I enable the unsafe cipher?

**Background**

I have an old printer (Xerox 6140N) that works fine. It has a web server to control the setup. Security-wise it is not a problem, as the server is not publicly accessible. I cannot change the web server, thus not upgrade it to a higher TLS-version.

I would prefer a solution like [Firefox: Secure Connection Failed SSL_ERROR_BAD_MAC_ALERT](https://superuser.com/questions/1280239/firefox-secure-connection-failed-ssl-error-bad-mac-alert/1280240) so that I can lower the security for this site only - and not in general.

I simply do not understand why the browsers allow for http but not for insecure https: No matter the setup, the security of https is not lower than http. I am, however, perfectly OK with a warning that makes it clear, that this is not much better than pure http.

The printer supports these:

```
$ nmap --script ssl-enum-ciphers -p 443 mysite
Starting Nmap 7.80 ( https://nmap.org ) at 2020-09-05 09:02 CEST
Nmap scan report for mysite (192.168.1.314)
Host is up (0.00060s latency).

PORT    STATE SERVICE
443/tcp open  https
| ssl-enum-ciphers: 
|   SSLv3: 
|     ciphers: 
|       TLS_RSA_EXPORT_WITH_DES40_CBC_SHA - E
|       TLS_RSA_EXPORT_WITH_RC4_40_MD5 - E
|       TLS_RSA_WITH_3DES_EDE_CBC_SHA (rsa 1024) - D
|       TLS_RSA_WITH_AES_128_CBC_SHA (rsa 1024) - A
|       TLS_RSA_WITH_AES_256_CBC_SHA (rsa 1024) - A
|       TLS_RSA_WITH_DES_CBC_SHA (rsa 1024) - D
|       TLS_RSA_WITH_RC4_128_MD5 (rsa 1024) - D
|       TLS_RSA_WITH_RC4_128_SHA (rsa 1024) - D
|     compressors: 
|       NULL
|     cipher preference: client
|     warnings: 
|       64-bit block cipher 3DES vulnerable to SWEET32 attack
|       64-bit block cipher DES vulnerable to SWEET32 attack
|       64-bit block cipher DES40 vulnerable to SWEET32 attack
|       Broken cipher RC4 is deprecated by RFC 7465
|       CBC-mode cipher in SSLv3 (CVE-2014-3566)
|       Ciphersuite uses MD5 for message integrity
|       Forward Secrecy not supported by any cipher
|       Weak certificate signature: SHA1
|   TLSv1.0: 
|     ciphers: 
|       TLS_RSA_EXPORT_WITH_DES40_CBC_SHA - E
|       TLS_RSA_EXPORT_WITH_RC4_40_MD5 - E
|       TLS_RSA_WITH_3DES_EDE_CBC_SHA (rsa 1024) - D
|       TLS_RSA_WITH_AES_128_CBC_SHA (rsa 1024) - A
|       TLS_RSA_WITH_AES_256_CBC_SHA (rsa 1024) - A
|       TLS_RSA_WITH_DES_CBC_SHA (rsa 1024) - D
|       TLS_RSA_WITH_RC4_128_MD5 (rsa 1024) - D
|       TLS_RSA_WITH_RC4_128_SHA (rsa 1024) - D
|     compressors: 
|       NULL
|     cipher preference: client
|     warnings: 
|       64-bit block cipher 3DES vulnerable to SWEET32 attack
|       64-bit block cipher DES vulnerable to SWEET32 attack
|       64-bit block cipher DES40 vulnerable to SWEET32 attack
|       Broken cipher RC4 is deprecated by RFC 7465
|       Ciphersuite uses MD5 for message integrity
|       Forward Secrecy not supported by any cipher
|       Weak certificate signature: SHA1
|_  least strength: E
```

Answer (score 0):

You'll probably need to use an older version of firefox.  Newer versions are making it more difficult to connect to insecure sites, and sometimes the work-arounds they give just don't work.

Try one of the 60-series ESR versions.
(https://ftp.mozilla.org/pub/firefox/releases/68.9.0esr/win64/en-US/)